# Win32 API - RegisterClassEx errors

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, registerclass

I'm trying to open a simple window through the Win32 API, using the VC++ compiler and in Visual Studio. I'd like to know why the class fails; I've tried allocating it without a pointer, along with allocating it as a pointer and sending it to the function as a reference. Yet, no matter what I try, the `RegisterClassEx` function refuses to return true.

Why is this, and what can be done about it?

**From `WinMain`**

```
WNDCLASSEX* wc = new WNDCLASSEX;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG     msg;
    bool    done;

    wc->style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc->lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc->cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc->cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc->hInstance = hInstance;
    wc->hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc->hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc->hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc->lpszClassName = L"someclass";

    if (!RegisterClassEx(wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Class registration has failed!", L"Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The error code is probably ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER because you didn't initialize all the members of WNDCLASSEX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to tell Windows how large your `WNDCLASSEX` structure is by filling in the `cbSize` member. You failed to initialize this member before calling `RegisterClassEx`, which is presumably why that function is failing. The `sizeof` operator is all you need.

You also failed to initialize some of the other members of the structure, like `lpszMenuName`. If you don't explicitly initialize them, they contain garbage data, which is probably causing the `RegisterClassEx` function to fail. If you're not using them, you need to explicitly set them to 0.

Furthermore, just because the `RegisterClassEx` argument accepts a pointer to a `WNDCLASSEX` structure doesn't mean that you have to *create* the structure as a pointer. You can create a regular object on the stack and use the address-of operator (`&`) to pass a pointer to the function.

Note that, as per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587.aspx), you can also call the [`GetLastError` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) to get more details on what went wrong when calling the `RegisterClassEx` function. This will help you to debug problems when you encounter them.

Working sample code:

```
WNDCLASSEX wc    = {0};  // make sure all the members are zero-ed out to start
wc.cbSize        = sizeof(wc);
wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
wc.lpszClassName = L"someclass";

if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Class registration has failed!",
               L"Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    return 0;
}
```