# Access read violation at 0xccccc

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, runtime-error

I have no idea why this is happening; some Google searches have led me to believe it is due to improper memory-management, while others have stated it is because of an invalid .DLL linked to the executable. I cannot seem to figure this out, because the only .DLL I could think of being invalid is my freeglut .DLL, yet that was working fine on its own without any problems.

All I'm trying to do is create a window.

**Question**

What is happening with my code? What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

**Code**

**`WinMain`**

```
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG     msg;
    bool    done;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"someclass";

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) { //Error: 
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Class registration has failed!", L"Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(
        L"someclass", L"someclass", 
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU,
        200, 200, 400, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL
        );

    if (!hwnd) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }

    done = false;

    while(!done) {
        PeekMessage(&msg, hwnd, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE);

        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) { 
            done = true;
        } else {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return msg.wParam;

}
```

**`stdafx.h`** <-- **precompiled header**

```
#ifndef STDAFX_H
#define STDAFX_H

#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>

#endif
```

**`WndProc`**

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    PAINTSTRUCT paintstruct;
    HDC hdc;
    LPCWSTR str = L"Hello, World!";

    switch(message) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &paintstruct);
        SetTextColor(hdc, COLORREF(0x00FF0000));
        TextOut(hdc, 200, 200, str, sizeof(str) - 1);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &paintstruct);
        return 0;
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_CREATE:
        return 0;   
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

**Official Error**

`Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.`

**Update**

Where the `//Error` comment is marked, by `RegisterClassEx`, in the `if` statement, is where the error occurs.

Comment: On which line of code does the access violation occur? That's the first step in determining the cause.

Comment: Where does the error occur?  `0xcc` is the fill character with which the debug runtime initializes the stack.  This error means that you are using an uninitialized variable--probably a pointer.

Comment: Could you post the code for `WndProc`?

Comment: Strangely enough, I'm not using a pointer. Regardless, I just updated my question(at the bottom) for clarity: it's where RegisterClassEx is called

Comment: @Mehrdad WndProc posted. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, you're the person who [just asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775443/win32-api-registerclassex-errors) and then explicitly ***did not follow my advice***. Most people would be smart enough to at least copy and paste the working sample code... You still aren't initializing all of the members of the `WNDCLASSEX` struct. And you have to initialize them even if you're not using them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not initialized all of the data members of `wc` (`hIconSm` and `lpszMenuName`).  You should zero-initialize `wc` before you start using it.  For example:

```
WNDCLASSEX wc((WNDCLASSEX()));
```

`0xcc` is the fill character with which the debug runtime initializes the stack before your function is entered.  When you see this value (and the value is not expected), it means that you are using a variable that you failed to initialize.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. Quick question: why did you wrap the `WNDCLASSEX()` in parens? Also, why pass that specifically and not just do `WNDCLASSEX wc();` is that a copy constructor?

Comment: `WNDCLASSEX wc();` is a function declaration (a _vexing_ function declaration).  `WNDCLASSEX wc(WNDCLASSEX());` is also a function declaration (a _most vexing_ function declaration).  The extra parentheses are required to make it a variable declaration.  You can, of course, use whatever method you like to initialize the variable.

Comment: Much easier: `WNDCLASSEX wc = {};`  Or even `WNDCLASSEX wc = { sizeof wc };`

Comment: I always use the direct initialization syntax, for consistency.

Comment: Can't you write direct initialization as `WNDCLASSEX wc{ sizeof wc };` ?  But for a POD, there's no difference.

Comment: In C++11, `WNDCLASSEX wc{ sizeof wc };` would be the preferable way to do this, yes.  Unfortunately, not all compilers support C++11 uniform initialization (notably, Visual C++ does not yet support it).

Comment: I prefer: `WNDCLASSEX wc = WNDCLASSEX();` I feels easier to read. And optimization will remove the redundant copy.

Answer (score 7):

`0xCCCCCCCC` is a magic number, used by Microsoft's C++ debugging runtime library, to mark uninitialised stack memory. You don't indicate which line you're getting this error on, which makes it hard to say exactly which variable is uninitialised.

Other [magic numbers from this series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) include:

- `0xABABABAB`         Used by Microsoft's `HeapAlloc()` to mark "no man's land" guard bytes after allocated heap memory
- `0xBAADF00D`         Used by Microsoft's `LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED)` to mark uninitialised allocated heap memory
- `0xCDCDCDCD`         Used by Microsoft's C++ debugging runtime library to mark uninitialised heap memory
- `0xDDDDDDDD`         Used by MicroQuill's SmartHeap and Microsoft's C++ debugging heap to mark freed heap memory
- `0xDEADDEAD`         A Microsoft Windows STOP Error code used when the user manually initiates the crash.
- `0xFDFDFDFD`         Used by Microsoft's C++ debugging heap to mark "no man's land" guard bytes before and after allocated heap memory
- `0xFEEEFEEE`         Used by Microsoft's `HeapFree()` to mark freed heap memory

Comment: Might be nice to include a link to the source.